# Extra period on bookmarked questions section

Tags: bug, profile-page, bookmarks

The period symbol should be removed from the sentence in the *Bookmarks* section on the *Summary* tab of the profile page to be consistent with other sections.

> [image: Bookmarks]

You can see that on almost any [low participated user profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?page=24476&tab=reputation&filter=all).

Comment: IMO, the bug is that the other *sentences* don't have periods. If it was just "no bookmarked questions", then a period wouldn't be appropriate. However, all of those lines of text are written as complete sentences. As such, they should *each* have a period.